# What is happening while executing this command cd / | vi?

Tags: bash, shell, pipe, vi, stdin

When I execute the command `cd / | vi`, it goes to the vi editor. When I type any command it does not display the command but it gets executed and the command that is executed is not shown in the history.

Comment: try `cd /&& vi /path/to/file`

Comment: stty sane is working ,but in command history ,command what i have typed is not shown.

Comment: Answer to the question "what is happening" is that the output of the "cd /" command (which doesn't output anything) is piped to the input of vi, which doesn't like that as it expects input from the user on its standard input. So just don't do that.

Comment: What shell (bash, zsh, etc) are you typing this command in to? What terminal emulator (xterm, rxvt, urxvt, etc)0 are you using, if any?

Answer (score 1):

The "|" is a pipe command.  Some programs take their input from a pipe, such as "less" or "more".

If you run the following command:

```
$ ls -l | less
```

The output of "ls" will be piped through the pager, "less".

If you want to run one command then the other from the same line without the pipe you would either use ";" or "&&" (which is probably what you're looking for) instead of the pipe "|" command.

More direct to your question, what happens is your command is trying to output the content of "cd" to vi.